# error 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Could not find any usable binding services in WSDL.' connecting to SOAP client with PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i am connecting to a service that has no documentation available.  the URL is `https://data.tga.gov.au/ARTGSearch/ARTGWebService.svc`

i am trying to connect to this service using php 7.4. i have got the SOAP extension installed.

after hunting around SO, my connection code is:

```
  public function go()
  {
    $opts = [
      'http' => [
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
      ],
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $wsdlUrl = 'http://data.tga.gov.au/ARTGSearch/ARTGWebService.svc?wsdl';
    $soapClientOptions = array(
      'stream_context' => $context,
      'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    );
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);
    $params              = [];
    $params['pagestart'] = 1;
    $params['pageend']   = 2;
    $params['entrytype'] = 'medicine';
    $out = $client->ARTGSearchJson($params);
    var_dump($out);
  }
```

looking at the output of `http://data.tga.gov.au/ARTGSearch/ARTGWebService.svc?wsdl` it does seem legitimate, i can certainly see the method that i want to use.

i am not familiar with SOAP clients - does anyone have any ideas how i can use the service to use the ARTGSearchJson method?
(the vendors are not able to provide any documentation)

Comment: Check out this link https://github.com/zdavatz/cpp2sqlite/issues/92. It have a API document for the service you want.

Comment: The WSDL http://data.tga.gov.au/ARTGSearch/ARTGWebService.svc?wsdl is incomplete. It lacks the binding definition and the service does not contain an endpoint to match the binding. Compare with a structure example here  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language#Example_WSDL_file. So the error you get is correct. You need a complete WSDL to make the call with the PHPSoapClient. Or use the PHPSoapClient in non-wsdl mode. Or you can make POST requests to send the SOAP messages directly. Or you can try the JSON alternative as the other comment suggests.

Comment: the URL i needed changed slightly.  the required URL is now http://data.tga.gov.au/ARTGSearch/ARTGWebService.svc/json/ARTGValueSearch/?entrytype=medicine&pagestart=xxx&pageend=yyy